# Azure DevOps Artifacts getting deleted

Tags: azure-devops

I have a bunch of Azure Pipeline and Release packages.  The piplines build and publish my code to a testing environment every night, and as part of that publish they create artifacts used by the selenium testing software.

This has been working correctly for several years now.  Sometime around the last upgrade we did to Azure Devops the artifacts have started getting deleted after about a day instead of honoring the deletion schedule that I have setup.

The artifacts are generated by the pipeline packages and used by the release packages, and everything is working correctly.  However sometime after the last release has finished running for the night, all the artifacts get deleted.  I have tried running the entire process manually, and when it is done the artifacts still exist (at least until the next day - I haven't identified a specific time they get deleted), so the issue does not appear to be within any of the packages themselves.

The Settings Retention policy, I believe these apply to the pipelines.

[image]

The Release Retention policy, obviously these should apply to the release packages.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why my artifacts are not sticking around past 1 day?

Comment: Silly question: What about the storage space to store these artifacts? Did you check that?

Comment: It's a virtual drive attached to a virtual machine hosted in Azure.  There's lots of free space on the drive.  The artifacts hang around for hours after creation around 6pm, long enough for all the releases to run and use them, but are gone when I log in in the morning around 7am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have figured out the problem, and it appears to be a change in the way Azure Devops works with the newest version.  This is the first version I have noticed this issue in:

Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1

The settings indicate that artifacts should be kept for 20 days in my instance.  However, every time I run a build it over-writes the existing artifacts with the newest ones.  My guess is that this artifact path gets tied to the build in the database.  And since all artifact paths are identical in my case (something that did not occur to me to mention in the original post), deleting an artifact that is 20 days old will delete the data from the current artifact path as well.

I solved this issue for myself by including $(Build.BuildNumber) as part of my artifact path.  Unfortunately you cannot directly use a date variable in that path, however since I have the date built into my buildnumber this approach worked for me.